# Why this regex dosen't work on shell when using find

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, find

I have used this command on linux

```
sudo find . -type f -regex "^\.\/\.git[\w-\/]+"
```

to find the file `.git-credential-cache/` but it return nothing while I have tried this regex using (js) and it have worked successfully and matched with `.git-credential-cache/`.

Comment: Try `find . -type f -name '.git*'`

Answer (score 3):

It seems `find`'s default regex type doesn't support `\w` in the square brackets. In fact, none of the supported types on my machine understands it:

```
touch a b c
for type in findutils-default awk egrep ed emacs gnu-awk grep posix-awk \
        posix-basic posix-egrep posix-extended posix-minimal-basic sed ; do
    find . -type f -regextype $type -regex '\./[\w]'
done
# No output.
```

You can use a POSIX class in `posix-extended` type, though

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '\.\/\.git-[[:alnum:]/-]+'
```

Note that `^` is useless as the regex must match the whole path anyway. Similarly, there's no need to backslash a forward slash.

Also, if the file you search for is `.git-credential-cache/`, it's probably a directory rather than a file, as file names can't end in a slash. `-type f` would ignore directories, use `-type d` instead.

Comment: FYI: `[\w-\/]` matches more chars than `[[:alpha:]-]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: In find, `[\w-\/]` matches ``\`` and nothing else, it seems.

Comment: OP tried it in JS and it worked in JS. `[\w-\/]` *in JS* matches more chars than `[[:alpha:]-]` matches *in `find`*. What you suggest is not a direct equivalent and thus does not have to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot but do you mean that [\/] will match / and \ when i use find 
so you deleted it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I changed `alpha` to `alnum` and added `/` to the character class.